# Как преобразовать строку, полученную из базы данных?

Tags: php

Есть переменная которая выглядит так:

```
$text = "Большой {$arg} текст.";
```

Если её в коде оставить всё работает. Но я хочу текст редактировать через панель. Получается я сохраняю в БД и храню сообщение так:

```
Большой {$arg} текст.
```

Потом в коде я просто делаю так:

```
$text = $data["text"];
```

Проблема в том что переменная $arg не как не определяется. Текст так и выводиться:

```
Большой {$arg} текст.
```

Как научить код обрабатывать эту переменную?

Comment: `str_replace`, и да, так не надо делать.

Comment: @u_mulder почему так не нужно делать? лучше делать так: %arg% ?

Comment: Хотя бы так да. При указании `$arg` вы можете ошибочно поставить двойные кавычки в `str_replace` и получить замену не того чего ожидаете.

Comment: Можно на шаблонизаторе Twig `$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate('Hello {{ name }}'); $template->render(array('name'=>'World'));`.  Это безопасно.

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примитивный вариант. Использование функции [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php).

```
$textBD = 'тут ваш текст из БД';

$text = str_replace('{$arg}', $textBD, $data["text"]);
```

Но лучше вашу задачу как-то перепроектировать по другому. Например подсмотреть как это делается у шаблонизаторов или например система шорткодов у WP (в гугле где-то было объяснение как это работает).

Comment: Я вот как вопрос задал и сразу сам вспомнил про такую функцию. Спасибо за ответ.